# is a way to read the internal implementation of Apple's API on ios?

Tags: ios, api

I was just wondering if there is a way to read the internal implementation of Apple's API on ios? For example, is there a way I can see how "setNeedsDisplay()" function of UIView is implemented internally? I think this will help me understand how the code actually works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code to the Apple frameworks is not publicly-available. You can disassemble the framework code, but unless you're really good with assembly language, you probably won't learn much.